# Obtaining a security token for API integration

Tags: api, integration

I'm trying to setup a KeySurvey API integration for one of the Survey forms, with the goal of having the Survey push data back to the corresponding record in SF.

The one roadblock I'm running into is around the "Security Token" functionality in SF. Apparently, when I setup the integration through the UI on the KeySurvey application, it indicates that while I supplied the appropriate login and password, that a Security Token needs to be appended to the password for the integration user to successfully connect.

Our Salesforce environment does not seem to have the option to 'attain' a security token. I've logged in as the integration user, as well as myself to try and locate this functionality ("Reset Security Token" or something like that).

Any help please.

Comment: Nothing under Your Name | My Settings | Personal -> Reset My Security Token?

Comment: Does the user have API access?

Comment: Hi Phil, yes the user already has API access. There is nothing under Your Name | My Settings | Personal -> Reset My Security Token.

Comment: @Sara is this an enterprise edition org?

Comment: @Phil, yep this is enterprise org.

Comment: @Sara weird, so what do you see what you go to Your Name -> My Settings -> Personal? is there just no option on the left for reset my security token?

Answer (score 1):

I have had alsorts of trouble with users resetting the password and/or re-requesting security tokens for connected applications (e.g. automated dataloader) and so to get around this you can give network access to an IP or range of IPs. Any request falling in this range won't need the token. Just go to Setup>Security Controls>Network Access.

NOTE: there are implications of doing this (i.e security token functionality isn't required anymore) so use carefully and consider the information behind the 'help for this page' link.

Comment: Hi Richard - Our SF environment doesn't have network access in the setup area.

Comment: Perhaps you don't have api access - you'll need to check with your account manager if you have access or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hack to get the security token,
https://na3.salesforce.com/_ui/system/security/ResetApiTokenEdit?retURL=%2Fui%2Fsetup%2FSetup%3Fsetupid%3DPersonalInfo&setupid=ResetApiToken

Change the na3 to your salesforce server.
Thanks
Zishan

Comment: This just resets the security token. It is not possible to view an existing token because Salesforce does not store it in plain text.